# Conditional Normal Distribution. Intuition based on projection?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, covariance, linear-algebra, multivariate-normal-distribution

It is known that, when $(X,Y)^T\sim\mathcal{N}_{p+q}(\mu,\Sigma)$, $$X\mid Y\sim\mathcal{N}_p(\mu_{X\mid Y}, \Sigma_{X\mid Y}),$$
where $\mu_{X\mid Y}=\mu_X+\Sigma_{XY}\Sigma_{YY}^{-1}(Y-\mu_Y)$ and $\Sigma_{X\mid Y}=\Sigma_{XX}-\Sigma_{XY}\Sigma_{YY}^{-1}\Sigma_{YX}$.

Is there an intuition of understanding $\mu_{X\mid Y}$ and $\Sigma_{X\mid Y}$ based on a projection from $X$ to a vector space spanned by $Y$?

I ask this is because it really **looks like** a projection of $X$ on the vector space spanned by $(1,Y-\mu_Y)$, i.e.

$$\mu_{X\mid Y}=\mathbb{E}_X\left(\frac{\langle X,Y\rangle}{\langle  Y,Y\rangle}(Y-\mu_Y) + \langle X,1\rangle 1\right),$$ where $\langle X,Y\rangle $ is the inner product of two vectors $X$ and $Y$, defined as $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\langle X,Y\rangle$. However, it on the other hand, does not look strictly a projection, as $\langle X,1\rangle$ would be zero because $\langle X,1\rangle=\operatorname{Cov}(X,1)=0$. Is there a way of understanding the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ from a projection perspective? Thanks.